# MySQL Dynamic Result Query with column when values are on same column

Tags: mysql, query

I want to create a dynamic value based on election result. I've three table.

1. vote table
2. Candidate table
3. Candidate position table.

Here the candidate table and position table is dynamic. its means I haven't any control on it.

I want to make a view like this:
[image]

Here Ballton num come from vote table, president, general secretary and treasurer is come from candidate position table and against each ballot no all column will be populate.

Here are the rest of the table structure:

Vote:
[image]

Candidate:
[image]

Candidate position:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean when write "position table is dynamic"? Is it possible that this table will contain more records? How many columns do you expect to see in your final result set in this case?

Comment: Yes, re more positions and candidates can be created. If it is fixed, then I can solve it using CASE statement.

Comment: so you need a dynamic query, not a view

Comment: yes, dynamic query. Actually I meant that with dynamic result view. I don't need VIEW I just the query.

Comment: it would be great if you add code for table creation and data filling or even prepare it using https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: What is the Question?  What is the desired result?  Use text, not images.